# Using vega-embed with parcel gives an error

Tags: npm, vega-lite, vega, parcel

I wanted to use vega-embed in a javascript project using NPM.

I imported the library the following way :

```
 import * as vegaembed from "vega-embed";
```

However when I run `parcel src/index.html` I get the following error :

```
  /home/alexis/Projects/VisualQueries/VisualQueries/node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/log/index.js: /home/alexis/Projects/VisualQueries/VisualQueries/node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/log/index.js: Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`.
```

Any help ? I did not find any resource on the web for this error.

Comment: I had the same problems, but after installing with `npm install vega-...@version`, with the specific major versions outlined here https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#directly-in-the-browser it suddenly works.